# How to iterate JsonReader twice?

Tags: android, gson

I am facing the following problem: I have json like this

```
{
    "type": "objectType",
    "body": {
         //could be one of five different object types
    }
}
```

`"body"` could be one of fixed set of types so I am trying to implement custom TypeAdapter:

```
@Override
public MyObject read(final JsonReader pJsonReader) throws IOException {
    if (pJsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        pJsonReader.nextNull();
        return null;
    }

    pJsonReader.beginObject();
    String type = null;

    while (pJsonReader.hasNext()) {
        final String fieldName = pJsonReader.nextString();

        if (pJsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            pJsonReader.nextNull();
            continue;
        }

        switch (fieldName) {
            case TYPE: {
                tyoe = mStringTypeAdapter.read(pJsonReader);
                break;
            }
            case BODY: {
                body = //I need to choose a particular TypeAdapter basing on type field
            }
            default: {
                pJsonReader.skipValue();
            }
        }
    }

    pJsonReader.endObject();

    return MyObject(type, body);
}
```

The problem is that I need to choose TypeAdapter for `"body"` basing on `"type"` so I need to copy somehow JsonReader steam and iterate it once more time when I find `"type"`value.
Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: why `iterate it once more`? the `body` token comes after `type`.

Comment: @muratgu because I cannot be sure that I'll get a json with reversed order lile `"body"` part the first and `"type"` second

Comment: afaik android-gson reader does not have a `reset` feature. however, you could possibly re-create the reader and call it on the same stream twice, once for identifying the type, and the second for the body.

Answer (score 0):

If you are controlling the structure of the JSON, then it would be good to nest the *body* so you are always able to read the *type* first.

However, if you cannot change the structure of the JSON you could create an in-memory representation using [JsonParser](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) and then have the respective adapter for *type* read from that:

```java
public class MyObjectTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<MyObject> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, MyObject value) throws IOException {
        // You will have to implement this in case you are
        // also writing JSON data
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    
    @Override
    public MyObject read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            in.nextNull();
            return null;
        }

        String type = null;
        JsonElement body = null;

        in.beginObject();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String fieldName = in.nextString();

            if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                in.nextNull();
                continue;
            }

            switch (fieldName) {
                case "TYPE": {
                    type = in.nextString();
                    break;
                }
                case "BODY": {
                    body = JsonParser.parseReader(in);
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    in.skipValue();
                }
            }
        }
        in.endObject();

        // Get the corresponding adapter for `type`
        // Possibly also have to create this MyObjectTypeAdapter using a
        // TypeAdapterFactory to be able to use Gson for the adapter lookup
        TypeAdapter<?> bodyAdapter = ...
        
        return new MyObject(type, bodyAdapter.fromJsonTree(body));
    }
}
```

This won't be that efficient, but should not be a big issue if the *body* is not that complex.